# argparse - Optional argument after specific choice

Tags: python, argparse

I have a choice argument and was wondering how I could have an optional argument after 1 of those choices.

In code this is what I'm looking for

```
ops = {
  "foo": foo,
  "bar": bar,
  ...
}

parser.add_argument(
  "operation",
  choices=ops.keys(),
)

# I'm looking for something like this
parser.magically_select_choice("foo").set_optional_argument("--something", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()

func_args = []
args.something and func_args.append(True)
ops[args.operation](*func_args)
```

Comment: You probably want a subcommand, so that `script foo` and `script bar` each have their own set of follow-up arguments.

Comment: Create a normal '--something', and ignore it if the choice isn't 'foo'.

Comment: @chepner could you give me an example of how I could implement subcommands with choices?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: @chepner Thanks for that, but I don't see a way to add the subparser to only 1 choice.

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are the subcommands. You add `--something` to the `foo` subparser.

Comment: With subparsers, each subparser is a choice.  You add extra arguments to that parser.  That may be overkill for your case.